# Whenever i am trying to keep an object in state it showing this error in typscript,

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Data {
    petname: string,
    petprice: string,
    category: string,
    pettype: string,
    gender: string,
    short: string,
    details: string
}
```

```
    const [petdata, setPetdata] = useState<Data>({});
    const [img, setImg] = useState<string>('');
```

**Error:**
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data | (() => Data)'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type '() => Data'.
Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(): Data'

Comment: The error says it all, really. You say the state is of type Data, but then the initial value is `{}`, which is not of that type.

Comment: Either make properties optional or change the generic useState type accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the empty object you have provided as the default value upon initialisation, `{}`, does not match the `Data` interface as it is missing all the required properties in it. This is a good sign because that means TypeScript is doing its intended job: ensuring you don't assign objects that does not match the given interface.

Long answer: A solution will be to allow the state to be `Data` or `null`, so you can just instantiate it with `null` at the start until you have populated it later:

```
const [petdata, setPetdata] = useState<Data | null>(null);
```

Based on how your downstream code looks like, this change may lead to errors if you attempt to access properties inside the `petdata` object, e.g. `petdata.petname`, without first checking if `petdata` is nullish. This can be circumvented if you:

- use the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) when accessing sub properties, e.g. `petdata?.petname`, or
- have a type guard before accessing any properties, e.g.

  ```
  if (petdata) {
      petadata.petname = ...;
  }
  ```

---

Of course, a dirty escape hatch is to make all properties optional, i.e.:

```
const [petdata, setPetdata] = useState<Partial<Data>>({});
```

...but **I would not recommend this** for your case as that means you are no longer strict enforcing required properties on `petdata`, and these properties are likely to be compulsory/required by design.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in Java for example, Javascript does not really maintain classes at runtime. The TypeScript compiler does. Javascript maintains only "objects" with their properties and values (and methods of course, but in this case you only have properties). Those you defined are all obligatory, none of them are optional.

You can mark a property as optional by adding a `?` behind the variable's name, like this:

```
details?: string
```

So the compiler tries to match your parameter `{}` to an interface you defined, but nothing matches, because `Data` would need all those obligatory properties to match. The method needs either an object of type `Data` or a method, that returns a `Data` object.

So you've got two options: you define `Data`'s properties as optional, and therefore let `{}` match `Data` or pass all the data like this:

```
{
    petname: '',
    petprice: '',
    category: '',
    pettype: '',
    gender: '',
    short: '',
    details: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your state as follows will accepts empty objects

```
const [petdata, setPetdata] = useState<Data>({} as Data);
```